# create a file from python with owner specified

Tags: python

I am trying to create a file on linux with the owner:group predefined from a python script.

The problem is that the python script runs as root and I cant do the owner setting in 2 steps:

```
subprocess.call("cp a b", shell=True)
subprocess.call("chown user:group b", shell=True)
```

as the file creation has to trigger another process via incron that works on the file ownership . If I do it in 2 steps it always trigger a process as root (from the first cp);which I dont want

In short is there a simple way to create a file with the owner and group set at the creation time itself from a python process running as root .

Comment: `subprocess.call("cp a b;chown user:group b", shell=True)` ?

Comment: `subprocess.call("""su -c 'cp a b' user:group"""", shell=True)` ?

Comment: There is no need to use a shell and call these external programs, they are all available in Python.  For file copying see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html and for `chown`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html.

Comment: @cdarke, nice approach. Thanks to help us to keep open mind. We will wait for OP to know why he circumvented shutil and os python libraries.

Comment: Will use os. for copying . checking if @cdarke 's code works flawless in my situation . cant use cp -a as the owner will be different for different runs of the code and will be almost completly different from the owner of the file to be copied from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the current process effective uid and gid, but the new user must have read access to the file you are copying from. Is that OK?

```
import os
import shutil

gid = 20      # Target group id
uid = 501     # Target user id

os.setegid(gid)
os.seteuid(uid)

from_file = '/var/root/rootfile'       # File to copy from (tested on OS X)
to_file = 'rootfile'                   # Filename to copy to
shutil.copyfile(from_file, to_file)

# Switch back to root
os.setegid(0)
os.seteuid(0)
```

Comment: For completeness: If the target user does not have read access, you can make a [temporary copy of it](http://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) and make that readable by the target user.  If it's short enough, you can just pull it into memory.

Comment: Are we sure this works? I quickly tested it and after setting the UID away from 0 I was not allowed to return it to 0. Which makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is not a python but a UNIX problem:

A file is, by default, always created owned by the user of the creating process.

As root, you can change your effective UID for such operation, and you can change the file ownership afterwards.

`cp` supports keeping the original owner: `cp -a` This might already solve your problem.

Setting the UID in your python process is really trivial:

```
import os
os.setuid(<userid>)
```

Comment: If you're root, `setuid` is a bad idea because it will set real and saved UID as well.  On Linux, you can use `setresuid`, and on other systems `seteuid` should work.

Comment: I think @marcusMüller shoted too fast ;) Still some question comments not answered by OP.

Comment: @danihp Ah well, I never shoot too fast :) By principle! Kevin does have a point, though.